# Jquery mousedown vs click

Tags: javascript, jquery

today I discovered something that was quite confusing for me.
I just tried to hide s.th via jquery... first I tried to use this

```
$(".specificdiv li:nth-child(3)").click(function(){
    $(".anotherdiv").hide();
})
```

....but it does not work.

After a time I tried it this way:

```
$(".specificdiv li:nth-child(3)").mousedown(function(){
    $(".anotherdiv").hide();
})
```

Can anyone explain me why mousedown works instead of click?
Would be great to find out

EDIT

edited the anotherdiv.

Comment: can you show the problem in context?

Comment: Assuming this is just example content, but the `$(".anotherdiv").hide();` is not the same as `$(".another").hide();`

Comment: Post relavent HTML code. From what I see, both should work, unless you drag out of that without mouse up. Basically `click` = `mousedown` + `mouseup`.

Comment: Did you wrap your JS-Conde into `$(function(){ ... });`?

Comment: @Chris When the latter works, then it is not an issue of `$(document).ready(function(){});` stuff... :)

Comment: I can't see any other reason for the problem.

Comment: It's not the nature of jQuery to behave like you mentioned. It's more of a context oriented problem. So, if you can show us your code we would be able to help.

Comment: -1 for lack of HTML or demo... otherwise, there is no context here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Possible reasons:**

1. The event `mousedown` executes **before** `click`, so first come first serve.
2. The element might have already a `click` event, which prevents this from happening, say that function executes first and it has a `return false` statement in it.

Now since you are using `mousedown`, which is not assigned for this element, it doesn't have any conflicts. This *may be* a reason, because you didn't post the full code. Feel free to correct. :)

On a smaller note, you have `$(".anotherdiv").hide();` in the first code and `$(".another").hide();` in the second code, missing the `div` in the class. Is that a problem?

Comment: Even if the element has another click event handler, it should trigger both. So, that's not the problem. Moreover, even if the mousedown executes before click, removing the mousedown event would certainly make the click event fire normally. So, I think this is not the reason.

Comment: What if the other click handler is given first preference and it has a `return false` statement in it? Updated this in the answer. :)

Comment: I assume that a click handler can be given a first preference by writing it before the other handlers. And even if you return false in the first click handler, that shouldn't stop the other handlers from firing.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: I think that reason two sound really great to me, since there are other click events.
I'm not able to post the whole code, since this is from work and I got now connection from here to my sandbox.

$(".another").hide() ...should actually read $(".anotherdiv").hide().

sorry for confusing

Answer (score 1):

Actually the mousedown event is triggered when you push down the button, even you don't let the button up.
The click is like the mouseup, when you let the button go up.

In your code you have: ".anotherdiv" and ".another" could it be your error?