# Use both "d3.event.preventDefault" and "d3.event.which"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This code works perfect — except in **Internet Explorer 11**.
The `deleteNode(d)` only calls if the `mousedown` handle is commented out.

```
circle.enter().append('circle')
  .on('contextmenu', function (d) {
    deleteNode(d);
  })
  .on('mousedown', function (d) {
    setNode(d);
  });
```

That's why I try to catch right click with `mousedown`, but the context menu still appears.

```
circle.enter().append('circle')
  .on('mousedown', function (d) {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    if (d3.event.which == 3) {
      deleteNode(d);
    }
    setNode(d);
  });
```

How to fix not showing up the context menu or catching both `contextmenu` and `mousedown` events?

Comment: check the answer to this question, might be your cause...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839440/jquery-mousedown-vs-click

Comment: Thank you for your input! I don't have another "click" handler (just, touchend, mouseover, mouseend, dbltap) and it doesn't work with click.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are close to your own solution to the problem. All that is needed is already there, you just need to rearrange it a bit:

```
circle.enter().append("circle")
    .on("contextmenu", function(d) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("mousedown", function (d) {
        if (d3.event.which == 3) {
            deleteNode(d);  // <-- d probably needs to be replaced
        } else {
            setNode(d);    // <-- d probably needs to be replaced
        }
    });
```

This works for me in IE11 as well as in FF and Chrome.

As an aside, please note that `d` refers to the datum bound to the node, not to the node itself. Within the event listener `this` will refer to the current node.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");                
svg.append("circle")
    .attr({
        "cx": 100,
        "cy": 100,
        "r": 100
    })
    .on("contextmenu", function(e) {
        d3.event.preventDefault();
    })
    .on("mousedown", function (e) {
        if (d3.event.which == 3) {
          //console.log("deleteNode(d)");
        } else {
          //console.log("setNode(d)");
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg width="400" height="400">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great solution! Many script on bl.ocks.org use `event` instead of `d3.event`, which is ok for Chrome but not for FF.